# Outlook Interop Exception

Tags: c#, com, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

Trying to automate Outlook as

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();    
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

and getting following exception at second line i.e. `GetNamespace`

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass'  to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'.  This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component  for the
>   interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'  failed
>   due to the following error: No such interface supported  (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I am using `.Net Framework 4` and `Outlook 2013`.

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347529/outlook-2007-from-c-sharp-com-exception-type-e-libnotregistered) the only solution!!! as I am trying to avoid making any changes to the registry.

**Edit**

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347529/outlook-2007-from-c-sharp-com-exception-type-e-libnotregistered) didn't fix the problem.

**Edit**
If the referenced library is Office 15 and the installed library is 10 or 12, would it work?

Comment: trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656360/unable-to-cast-com-object-microsoft-outlook-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I've been stumped by this problem for days. This worked for me:

I just realized that Outlook 2013 is 64 bit... And my C# app had in Project Properties -> Build "Any CPU" as platform target and a check-mark in "Prefer 32-bit".

I changed the Platform target to x64 and it worked!

Comment: Wow, this fixed my issue after upgrading Office. The error message isn't really all that clear, weird thing is that I was using 64bit before and it was working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This exception usually happens when you had two versions of Office installed and then uninstalled one. Run a repair installation for your still installed Office, this should fix the registry keys.

Answer (score 1):

The exception looks quite obvious, this should work

```
    var myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

you just can't get a cast exception with that line above.

Comment: The exception is being thrown while getting namespace i.e. `myApp.GetNamespace`. However, i tried this and the exception is thrown once again `var myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); var mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix of the 9.5 version didn't work for me, as there was no excessive 9.5 field.

In my case, the problem was that when I downgraded to Outlook 2010 I have modified the installation location (i.e. not in the default ProgramFiles folder).
However, windows didn’t update accordingly the value in ‘HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\9.4\0\win64’.

After manually updating the value and pointing it to the right location, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same error message you have, my problem was I had installed Office 2016 x64 while the app that was trying to call into it was compiled as x86. Switching to x86 Office 2016 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I use Mobisynapse desktop app to update my Android Calendar and contacts.  Using Office 2010 I decided to upgrade to Office 2016.  After seeing it was a Office 365 product I uninstalled it.  This caused the Registry to change the Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies to change from 32 bit to 64 bit.  The Mobisynapse MB4Outlook started reporting sync error "Sync Failed".
Mobisynapse – Moffice error   3/31/19
Sync Failed – there is a problem with outlook – on the desktop 
When I click on Auto Sync settings I get “Please update MB4Outlook add-in first”  From where it is installed with your app.

Solution to this problem occurs when you try an Office365 product that is 64bit and have a 32 bit of office 2007-2013 installed.
Step 1: uninstall Office xxxx primary interop assemblies. If the package is not found download from here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=3508  Install it.
Step 2: run Office xxxx Install and select repair.
Step 3: Reboot and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same error exactly in the same place:

```
Outlook.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

I have a Win 10 and Office 365 - both 64 bits - with no previous Office installation; I tried several solutions above and did too Office quick repair, to no avail.
After running a Office online repair it functions like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
   //DECLARE
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;

  //INITIALISE
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.Session;
```

Answer (score -1):

For me removing 9.5 entry from this registry works:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`