# Outlook 2010 COM hresult: 0x80040155 Exception on c# app, but only on my Workstation

Tags: c#-4.0, com, interop, office-interop, outlook-2010

We have a c#-4.0 Click Once WinForm application with a DataGrid that displays a list of .msg files that have been saved on our file server, and when the user double clicks on a row in the grid, it opens the corresponding .msg file. This app is deployed to over a dozen workstations (all running W7 64Bit Pro with Outlook 2010) and it works without issue, I'm the only one getting this exception so the issue appears to be with Outlook on my workstation and not necessarily the app.

The Namespaces used on the form that contains the DataGrid:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Globalization;
```

The References in the Visual Studio 2010 Project:

- Microsoft.Office.Core Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (Verson 14.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities
- Microsoft.Office.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities

In the GridView's DoubleClick event:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

// The following line is where the exception is thrown.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(Settings.Default.msgFilePath + @"\SL_Imported_Files\Customer\OLI\PA\SL_Int_" + inID + ".msg");
if (mail != null)
    mail.Display(false);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
mail = null;
```

The Exception Message:

> {"Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155)."}

I've checked the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347529/outlook-2007-from-c-sharp-com-exception-type-e-libnotregistered) thread and my `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` is `9.4`, also no other version of Outlook as ever been install on my workstation except for 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was related to my old workstation and its Office install. I recently moved to a new workstation with a fresh Windows and Outlook 2010 install and this issue has disappeared.